# Xtensor random::randn returning number number below lower bound and above upper bound

Tags: c++, random, xtensor

I am trying to generate random numbers of shape {10} and range between -0.5 and 0.5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xrandom.hpp>

int main() {
    xt::xarray<double> a = xt::random::randn<double>({10}, -0.5, 0.5);
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

but it's returning an array

```
{-0.432735, -0.573191, -0.269675, -1.435692, -0.418144, -0.607127,
 -0.350702, -0.913972, -0.494892,  0.027733}
```

where -0.573191 is smaller and -1.435692 is bigger than range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`randn`](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xrandom.html#random-randn-function-reference):

```cpp
template<class T, class S, class E = random::default_engine_type>
auto xt::random::randn(const S& shape, T mean = 0, T std_dev = 1,
                       E& engine = random::get_default_random_engine())
```

The function draws numbers from [`std::normal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) and you've set the mean value to be `-0.5` and the standard deviation to be `0.5`. These are not lower and upper bounds.

---

You may want to use the [`rand`](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xrandom.html#random-rand-function-reference) function instead:

```
template<class T, class S, class E = random::default_engine_type>
auto xt::random::rand(const S& shape, T lower = 0, T upper = 1,
                      E& engine = random::get_default_random_engine())
```

This draws numbers from [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) - so, it's not the same thing, but it has a lower and an upper bound.

Comment: yeah, that was fast. is there a way to set upper and lower bounds in randn or is there any other function

Comment: @JaisalFrancis I added a function with `uniform_real_distribution` to the answer.

Comment: @JaisalFrancis It seems someone removed the comments. The answer did help you to solve the problem, right? It would be good if someone with a similar problem in the future is able to see that the answer helped in some way, if only in comments.

Comment: of course it helped me. I didn't remove the comments. It's strange. probably mods.

Comment: @JaisalFrancis Yes, they do that sometimes if the comments doesn't seem to help the answer, but in this case, I thought they did :-)

Comment: Yep. Btw you DP look like Walter White :-)

Comment: @JaisalFrancis Call me Heisenberg :-)